# Give read permission of all users table to a new user in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to provide read permission of all users table to a new user in oracle?

Answer (score 2):

One-by-one, there's no magic command which would do it "at once".

Every user should run

```
grant select on my_first_table to a_new_user;
```

statement(s).

---

True, you can write code to write code for you, e.g.

```
SQL> select 'grant select on ' || tname || ' to a_new_user;' as command
  2  from tab
  3  order by tname;

COMMAND
-------------------------------------------------------------
grant select on BONUS to a_new_user;
grant select on CHALLEN_HEADER to a_new_user;
grant select on CONFIG to a_new_user;
grant select on CUSTOMER to a_new_user;  
<snip>
```

and now copy/paste that bunch of `GRANT` statements into your client (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, whatever) and run them.

Or, you could **spool** result of that statement into a file and then run the file.

Or, even create a PL/SQL (anonymous? Stored?) procedure which would accept a parameter - a new user's name - and grant privilege(s) in one go.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should have a ROLE for each 'class' of users, then grant the privs to that role. Then as new users come in, just grant the role to the users:

```
CREATE ROLE BUSINESS_USER;
GRANT SELECT ON APP_SCHEMA.EMPLOYEE_TABLE TO BUSINESS_USER;
GRANT SELECT ON APP_SCHEMA.DEPARTMENT_TABLE TO BUSINESS_USER;
```

Then, as you get new users:

```
GRANT BUSINESS_USER TO BOB;
GRANT BUSINESS_USER TO CAROL;
GRANT BUSINESS_USER TO TED;
GRANT BUSINESS_USER TO ALICE;
```